# Having issues with regex matching wrong URLs in NGINX rewrite

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Hi I have urls that look like this

http://dansawesomesite.com/123/articlename

I have the following rewrite rule in nginx

```
location ~* /(\d+)/([\+\w-\ ]+)/?$ {
  try_files $uri /wpcontentredir.php?slug=$1;
}
```

This matches the above URL however the issue comes about when I have the following URL's

http://dansawesomesite.com/posts/630325/like
(as well as a number of similar)

These also end up getting matched which is correct based on my regex, but will mess things up as I dont want these urls parsed through that try_files, I just want them to pass as is.

Just wondering if anyone can help me with only matching the top first URL?

CHeers
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add "^" to the beginning of regexp
location ~* ^/(\d+)/([+\w-\ ]+)/?$

So it will match only if first part of URI contains digits and not "posts" or something

Comment: sorry I meant to reply to my own comment that I fixed this with

    if ($request_uri ~* ^/(\d+)/([\+\w-\ ]+)/?)
    {
 rewrite ^/(.*)$ /wpcontentredir.php?slug=$1;
 break;
    }